# Consulta de LINQ en .NET VISUAL STUDIO

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

Necesito traducir la siguiente consulta de `SQL` a `LINQ` en `.NET` con C#:

Esta es la consulta SQL a traducir:

```
SELECT COUNT(id_documento)
FROM documento
```

Necesito que el valor sea almacenado en una variable o que logre captar la cantidad de registros en una variable. Algo similar a una estructura así:

```
var OrdersByCustomer = db.Salesorders.GroupBy(so => so.CustomerId)
                                     .Where(tos => tos.Count() > 5)
```

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu pregunta. La consulta sql que pones nada tiene que ver con el Linq que pones como ejemplo.

Comment: No sé, pero siento que falta todo.

Comment: ¿Quieres contar los documentos por grupo o el total de grupos?

Comment: cual es el ojeto del que quieres extraer la informacion ? 
presiento que nisiquiera te haz conectado a SQL para extraer la informacion

Answer (score 9):

De la siguiente manera para contar los valores id_documento únicos para el lenguaje **C#**:

**Utilizando LINQ:**

```
var Consulta = (from x in db.Salesorders select id_documento).Distinct().Count();
```

**Utilizando Entity Framework:**

```
var Consulta = db.Salesorders.GroupBy(x => x.id_documento)
                             .Select(x => x.First())
                             .ToList()
                             .Count;
```

De la siguiente manera para contar los valores id_documento únicos para el lenguaje **VB**:

**Utilizando LINQ:**

```
Dim NumElementosDistintos = (From x In db.Salesorders 
                            Select x.id_documento)
                            .Distinct()
                            .Count
```

Con la siguiente consulta puedes contar la cantidad de id_documento totales en la tabla para el lenguaje **C#**:

**Utilizando LINQ:**

```
var Consulta = (from x in db.Salesorders select id_documento).Count()
```

> ó

```
var count = db.Salesorders.Count();
```

Con la siguiente consulta puedes contar la cantidad de id_documento totales en la tabla para el lenguaje **VB**:

**Utilizando LINQ:**

```
Dim NumElementos = (From x In db.SalesOrder Select x.id_documento).Count
```

> Puedes ver ejemplos de cómo utilizarlos en los siguientes enlaces:
>
> [Ejemplos de la consulta LINQ **En español**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/gg509017.aspx)
>
> [101 Ejemplos del uso de LINQ: Count - Simple y Count - Condicional
>   **En inglés**](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Aggregate-Operators-c51b3869/description#CountSimple)
>
> [101 Ejemplos del uso de LINQ: Select - Simple **En inglés**](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-09787825#SelectSimple1)
>
> [Aggregation Operations (Visual Basic) **En inglés**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/linq/aggregation-operations)
>
> [How to: Count, Sum, or Average Data by Using LINQ (Visual Basic) **En
>   inglés**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/how-to-count-sum-or-average-data-by-using-linq)

Answer (score 4):

**Utilizando lambda:**

```
var count = db.documento.ToList().Count();
```

**Utlizando Linq:**

```
var count = (from d in db.documento).Count();
```

> Estoy asumiendo que estas utilizando entity framework en tu proyecto.

Comment: no veo la expresion lambda en el primer caso xD

Comment: Tienes toda la libertad de ofrecer tu solución si asi lo deseas. :)

Comment: Cual es mas óptima? si no es mucha molestia

Comment: @Corpex esta respuesta la encuentras en este link :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391370/is-it-linq-or-lambda

Comment: gracias por la aclaración

Answer (score 2):

**Podrías hacerlo de esta maner**a.

> SELECT COUNT(id_documento) FROM documento

*Esta consulta se traduce en `LINQ`:*

```
var consulta = from documento in db.Salesorders select id_documento;
var cantidad = consulta.Count();
```

O puede hacerlo de la siguiente:

```
Dim consultaCount = Aggregate documento In db.Salesorders 
                          Into Count()
```

Eso ser me ocurre en base a tu infomación.Saludos.